# hands not responding as expected on oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, quest

I'm trying to develop an app to Oculus Quest 
yet i encounter many issues on the way.
the app basically consist of a room and teleportation.
the issue i encountered happens both on unity 2018.3.12 and 2019.1.8.

I created an app that did work as expected before on Quest using Oculus integration v1.35.
however, when re-exported and installed to a brand new Quest device:

1. teleportation that worked before refuse to work
2. pressing a button on 1 controller hids the other one from view.
3. hands movement is limited
4. even though target devices is set to Quest, I still (on v1.35) see the controller of oculus go
   [image]
5. it only happens when exporting to quest, on rift it works just fine.

from the posts in Oculus Forum

https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/comment/702108#Comment_702108

https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/79144/hands-not-showing-up-with-localavator-unity#latest

it looks like there is a firmware issue (but then you should be encountering that too no?)

**things I tried:**

1. Start a new project from scratch:

   followed the standard tutorial and documentation like those
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiJpjnzW-mw&t=1s

   https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/quest/latest/concepts/book-unity-gsg/

   could not see the hands at all, and no teleportation was implemented, it is said that there is a bug in current v1.39
   https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/79144/hands-not-showing-up-with-localavator-unity
2. I tried to use both the unity OVR assets and the following plugins
   https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/vr-movement-system-for-oculus-47292

   https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/vr-arc-teleporter-61561
   and in all 3 encountered the same issue.

did anyone encounter any issue similar to what's described?

as said, i expect to see the ands and controllers, and the code attached to the trigger press executed. none of this happened.

as some test, (since i do not have another quest)
i exported a build and sharing here.
please comment if you have tried it and it workd fine on your quest or not
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvcmhyar2qljb19/k14.apk?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all the helpers.

update 1:
if hands don't appear at all, its because Oculus integration 1.39 is buggy
revert to 1.38
https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/unity-integration-archive/

second:

the problem is that the latest firmware update added GO  controller support and defaulted it.
so Quest controllers begun appearing as GO
the trick was to copy the AndroidManifest to Assets/Plugins and edit it properly to specifically define the correct settings.
you can see the recommended changes here
https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/quest/latest/concepts/mobile-native-manifest/?fbclid=IwAR3AgasGPJFVGsz7lyzfJNfuTB8R1FOg88Quq8YZz67eQlwEFvgEMDGjSdo

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it's seems like an update issue with your device. 
Check references with the new device .
For me when i publish i use the 2018.4.1f LTE 
Since i encountered a lot of issues with android build with the 2019 version. 
Go to the company and ask what changed with the new versions.

Comment: thanks, Yud
you can check my answer below to see what I came with so far to solve it

Comment: thank you, what I didn't solve is that the controllers appear as Rift Controllers, not Quest